# setting each last radiobutton per list

Tags: jquery, list, radio-button

I need to fill a lot of radiobuttonlists with like one click, for example: is question one (with answer-choices yes/no) = yes, set every last/first radiobutton per list with a class.

I first had something like:

```
 $('.radiolist110 input[type="radio"]').last().prop('checked', true);
    $('.radiolist110').css("color", "#999999");
```

For every single radiolist, but thats a long list, so i tried to give all of the list, the same classname="automaticallyAnswered", so I only have one or two lines of code in the script-tag. What that does to me unfortunately is to give every div with the class the color, but only the very last radiobutton is checked. Using $('.radiolist.automaticallyAnswered Input[... didn't work eighter.

I am sure there is something like foreach .radiolist with .automaticallyAnswered, set last prop .... but I wasn't able to find.

Br

Comment: Please post your html

Comment: Sounds like the selector you want is: `$('.radiolist110').find('input[type="radio"]:last')` (ie: find the last `radio` in each `.radiolist110`)

Comment: Awesome, it works like a charm :)
But ... why is it that the "find ... :last" is so different from the .last() I used? Huh

Comment: because you're calling `last()` on the collection of `.radiolist110 input[radios]`, so it'll only return the last element from that collection

Comment: Ah I see, yes that makes sense. Sadly you postet a comment, so I cant rate that answer afaik, awesomehelp nevertheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current selector will only return one element:

```
$('.radiolist110 input[type="radio"]').last()
```

..because you're getting a collection of all `input[type="radio"]` within `.radiolist110`, but then getting only the last element in that collection when you call `last()`.

You need to get the last `input[type="radio"]` in each `radiolist110`:

```
$('.radiolist110').find('input[type="radio"]:last');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery each documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/